# How to Compile the Xamarin.iOS app using Visual Studio only?

Tags: xamarin.ios

Recently i came to know that Xamarin 3 got released and there a is beautiful GUI designer for iOS. But am not sure still for compilation do we need to use the Mac? With out Mac is it possible to compile iOS app?

Thanks,

Ravi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With invention of GUI designer for iOS in Xamarin, makes it easy for the developer to switching between xCode to windows. For compiling there is no need of Mac. But to run and see the output, you still require Mac - iOS build host. Also, Mac would be required to host iOS app on App store.

Comment: Thanks, But if we can have that run/host option in Visual studio itself then my life become easier without two machines(Windows with VS and Mac)

Comment: Yes that's true! But for some reason Apple like selling computers ;) You still can manage with a single machine. You can install windows on VM(Virtual Machine) on Mac and do the stuffs with a single machine.